I have not collected my relieving letter and experience letter form my first company
I worked in my first company for 6 months and left after submitting my registration letter. But I could not collect my relieving letter and experience letter or any other documents from them. It's been a year since I left that company, now I want to go back to work. So is it right to ask those documents or should I just remove my experience from my resume and start from beginning.

India, I assume. Relieving letters seem a uniquely Indian economic barrier.

What is preventing you from contacting the company and asking for these documents?

Does this answer your question? What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?

I had submitted my resignation letter but they did not process it to the next step. Even after one week, they did not discuss with me my resignation whenever I asked they said they were still discussing it. So I left the company without informing them. After that, I was busy preparing for my government exams and I was not willing to come back to the IT field again. But now because of financial issues, I have to work again.

So what is the status now? Did they process your resignation in the meantime? Do they still pay you?

No they have not contacted me since I left.

And you? did you contact them again as suggested by @alroc ?

@Reshma, Police your own language. You did inform them. That's what the resignation letter was for. Now perhaps the problem may be that they didn't accept your resignation, or that you didn't finish your full notice period (outlined in your contract/employee handbook), but that's another matter entirely. It's important to use the correct language when discussing these things. You don't want to make it sound worse than it is. Now, I don't know the law in India, but to me, having an employer not accept your resignation (for a non-military/non-life-and-death situation) would be absolutely insane.

There is no right or wrong.  And there is no harm in asking, the worse they can do is say No.  Besides, surely you need the Relieving letter.  Make an appointment and ask for it politely.
